# How to port a Ubuntu 18.04 playbook to KDE Neon

Tags: ansible, kde-plasma

I have a running playbook for Ubuntu xenial and bionic (18.04). As KDE Neon is based on Ubuntu 18.04 the assumption is that scripts would run straight out of the box. However `ansible_distribution` returns `KDE Neon` instead of `Ubuntu` which breaks a lot of roles and functionality in my case.
Is there a workaroud so that the roles etc do not have to be modified?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, simply modify the `ansible_distribution`:

```
- set_fact: ansible_distribution="Ubuntu"
  when: ansible_distribution == 'KDE neon'
```

Run this as a pre_task after gathering the facts. For all I know the setup (gathering the facts) resets this override so don't rerun the setup later on.

In case something doesn't work as expected add this task to check if you have the correct values:

```
- name: Multiline test on the ansible_distribution
  debug:
      msg: "{{ msg.split('\n') }}"
  vars:
    msg: |
      ansible_distribution: {{ ansible_distribution }}
      ansible_distribution_major_version: {{ ansible_distribution_major_version }}
      ansible_distribution_release: {{ ansible_distribution_release }}
      ansible_distribution_version: {{ ansible_distribution_version }}
```